# Add Dynamic Textbox if Radio Button is selected + Alert bug

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I have 2 problems that i am not able to solve:

1. The code should show me a Alert if everything is correctly saved. I made that alert message, but if i add 10 elements and click save, i get 10 alerts.
2. Unable to add dynamical textfield after i press the Radio Button in the drop down. I did a lot of things, but whenever i implant it, indexedDB stops working.

Bonus question if somebody knows the answer to:
3. How can i save the Forms i made in the Forms tab, so i can search them later and put new info in?

```js
var db;
function indexedDBOk() {
    return "indexedDB" in window;
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    //No support? Go in the corner and pout.
    if(!indexedDBOk) return;
    var openRequest = indexedDB.open("idarticle_people4",1);
    openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
        var thisDB = e.target.result;
        if(!thisDB.objectStoreNames.contains("people")) {
            thisDB.createObjectStore("people", {autoIncrement:true});
        }
    };
    openRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
        db = e.target.result;
        //Listen for add clicks
        document.querySelector("#addButton").addEventListener("click", addPerson, false);

        openRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
            alert('success: version 1 opened');
        };

        //Listen for get clicks
        document.querySelector("#getButton").addEventListener("click", getPerson, false);
    };
    openRequest.onerror = function(e) {
    }
},false);

function addPerson(e) {
    //console.log(i);
    var person= new Array(polje2);
    for (n=0; n<i; n++) {
        person.length=i;
        var element='#element';
        element+=n;
        var unos='#unos';
        unos+=n;
        var provjera = document.querySelector(element).type;
        var polje1 = document.querySelector(unos).innerHTML;
        if (provjera=='checkbox') {
            var polje2 = document.querySelector(element).checked
            }
        else {
            polje2 = document.querySelector(element).value
             }
    if (polje2==='') {
        alert ('Uspješno snimljeno');
    }
        //default for OS list is all, default for type is read
    var transaction = db.transaction(["people"],"readwrite");
    //Ask for the objectStore
    var store = transaction.objectStore("people");
    person[n]=
    {pitanje: polje1, odgovor:polje2 };
}
 //Perform the add
    var request = store.add(person);
    request.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log("Error",e.target.error.
            name);
        //some type of error handler
    };
    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
        console.log("Jej, uspjelo je");
    }
}
function getPerson(e) {
    var key = document.querySelector("#key").value;
    if(key === "") return;
    var transaction = db.transaction(["people"],"readonly");
    var store = transaction.objectStore("people");
    var request = store.get(Number(key));
    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
        var result = e.target.result;
        if(result) {
            var s = "<h2>Forma broj: "+key+"</h2><p>";
            for(var j=0; j<result.length; j++) {
                    s+= (result[j].pitanje + ': ' + result[j].odgovor  + "<br/>");
            }
            document.querySelector("#status").innerHTML = s;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('element').style.visibility='visible'
        }
    }
}
// get allPeople



// Funkcija za pravljenje Elemenata
var i = 0;
var a = 1;
function mojaFunkcija() {
    var type1 = document.getElementById('type1').value;
    var type2 = document.getElementById('type2').value;
    var question = document.getElementById('question').value;
    var counter = 'Element';
    counter+= a;
    var prviElement=document.createElement('span');
    prviElement.textContent= counter + ':' +'  ';
    document.body.appendChild(prviElement);
    var pitanje= document.createElement('span');
    var unos='unos';
    unos += i;
    pitanje.id=unos;
    pitanje.textContent=question + ' ';
    document.body.appendChild(pitanje);
    var tip1 = document.createElement("input");
    var element='element';
    element += i;
    tip1.id=element;
    if (type1=='textbox') {
        tip1.type=type2
    } else {
        tip1.type=type1
    }
    document.body.appendChild(tip1);
    var linija1= document.createElement("br");
    document.body.appendChild(linija1);
    var linija2= document.createElement("br");
    document.body.appendChild(linija2);
    i++;
    a++;
}

function AddTextBox(elm) {
    var v = elm.value;
    var iCounter = elm.id.replace('type1', '');

    if (v == 'radio') {
        var textbox = document.createElement('input');
        textbox.type = 'text';
        textbox.id = 'txtSecond' + iCounter;
        elm.parentNode.insertBefore(textbox, elm.nextSibling);
    } else {
        //Ovaj kod ce da izbrise Textbox u slucaju da se izabere druga opcija.
        var rmv = document.getElementById('txtSecond' + iCounter);
        if (rmv != undefined) {
            rmv.remove();
        }
    }
}

function modify_value()
{
    var hidden_field = document.getElementById('test3');
    hidden_field.value = 'testvalue';

}
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #A9A9A9;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align:center;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #696969;}
input{
    text-align:left;
}

.hide {
    visibility: hidden
}

.h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
}

.h2 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn2 {
    background-color: #A9A9A9;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align:center;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left:580px;
}
/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn2:hover, .dropbtn2:focus {
    background-color: #696969;}
input{
    text-align:left;
}

.kocka {
    max-width: 291px;
    max-height: 94px;
    background-color: #91ceff;
    border: 20px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#91ceff;

}

.kocka2 {
    max-width: 291px;
    max-height: 94px;
    background-color: #91ceff;
    border: 20px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#91ceff;

}
/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.kocka2:hover, .kocka2:focus {
    background-color: #696969;}
input{
    text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pepo.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="basa.js"></script>
    <title>OnlineForms</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <!--Ovaj kod je za Main Page-->
    <Main class="kocka">
        <div align="left">
            <input type="button" class="dropbtn" value="Administration" onClick="window.location.reload();return false;"/>
            &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
            <button class="dropbtn" id="getAllButton">Forms</button>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div align="left">
            <input type="number" id="key" class="dropbtn"  Placeholder="Type the key value"/>
            <button class="dropbtn" id="getButton"> Search </button> 
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </Main>
    <!--Ovaj kod je za Elemente-->
    <div id="element" class="hide">
            <h1>Element <input type="text" class="dropbtn" id="question" value="" Placeholder="Type your question here"/>
            <select title="ddmenu" class="dropbtn" id="type1">
                <option selected disabled hidden value="Please select">Please select</option>
                <option value="textbox">textbox</option>
                <option value="checkbox">checkbox</option>
                <option value="radio">radio button</option>
                </select>
            <select title="ddmenu" class="dropbtn" id="type2">
                <option selected disabled hidden value="Please select">Please select</option>
                <option value="none">none</option>
                <option value="mandatory">mandatory</option>
                <option value="number">numeric</option>
            </select>
            </h1>
        <input type="button"  id="adddugme" class="dropbtn2" value="Add"  onclick="mojaFunkcija()"/>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button id="addButton" class='dropbtn'>Save</button>
        </div>
    <br>
    <br>
<div id="status"></div>
    <br>
<div id="status2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what this has to do with CSS, can you please clean your code to make significant to the problem?

Comment: I just removed the CSS tag, you are right.

If i clean it now i m afraid i ll lose other functionality. I can try it but i am not very experienced in this. I am still learning. 

Thx in advance